# is there a DoCmd.RunMacro method for running macros inside EXCEL and Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-office

I saw people use DoCmd.RunMacro to run macros inside ACCESS, and tired in vain to find a similar method for Excel and Word.

Is there a similar method at all?

thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling the macro from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Word, call [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb209121%28office.12%29.aspx).
In Excel, call [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213784%28office.12%29.aspx).